# Facebook like button pulling old meta description

Tags: facebook

So, here's my code:

```
<meta property="og:description"
      content="OnlyInStanCo is a site created so people can share their complaints, praise, or stories about what it's like to live in, grow up in, work in, or anything else in the black hole affectionately known as StanCo. ">
```

I've ran the linter tool on the site, but it still pulls an old description.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send your URL to the form on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
It should reset cached meta information and also debug your page.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept.  I forgot about this question.  Sorry bud.

Answer (score 0):

Add `xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"` to your `<html>` opening tag, just before the `<head>` tag in your HTML document. This solved my problem.

e.g. `<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">`