# Facebook not correctly reading my og:description

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have defined my Open Graph tags in the head of my page. It is all working fine except the og:descrption tag. For some reason Facebook is reading my Meta Description into og:description instead of the og:descrption I explicitly define in the head.

I have run the page through the Facebook debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and the only error returned is as follows:-

***Inferred Property    The og:description property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.***

The page url is http://distinctfashionjewellery.ianryan.ie/index.php/amethyst-world-wonder-conf.html

Can anyone throw any light on what the issue may be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129218/facebook-like-button-pulling-old-meta-description/11419431#11419431

Check this may be this solve ur problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is it normal that your meta description tag "og:description" have an **contents** key instead of **content** ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, its `content=` not `contents=`

Comment: Thanks guys. A case of "not seeing the wood for the trees" I guess. Problem solved!